# How to union all and group by multiple select without null output?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problems when select by union and group by, there's null output on the output. Maybe because there's some multiple input with detailed data and some mathematics operation on the inside.
I have 1 view table with a primary key and have 2 foreign key that related with 2 table.

I've tried this code by union all and group by in the inside.

```
SELECT no_daftar,nama,(k1/jk1) as k1,(k2/jk2) as k2,(k3/jk3) as k3,(k4/jk4) as k4  FROM
(
SELECT no_daftar, nama,  SUM(k1) as k1,  SUM(k2)  as k2, SUM(k3) as k3, SUM(k4) as k4,
(SELECT COUNT(kode_aspek) FROM kriteria WHERE kode_aspek="K1" AND kode_aspek=a.kode_aspek) as jk1,
(SELECT COUNT(kode_aspek) FROM kriteria WHERE kode_aspek="K2" AND kode_aspek=a.kode_aspek) as jk2,
(SELECT COUNT(kode_aspek) FROM kriteria WHERE kode_aspek="K3" AND kode_aspek=a.kode_aspek) as jk3,
(SELECT COUNT(kode_aspek) FROM kriteria WHERE kode_aspek="K4" AND kode_aspek=a.kode_aspek) as jk4
    FROM 
(
SELECT no_daftar, nama, kode_aspek, nilai AS k1, 0 AS k2, 0 as k3, 0 as k4 FROM bobot WHERE kode_aspek =  'K1' AND tahun = 2019
UNION ALL
SELECT no_daftar, nama, kode_aspek, 0 AS k1, nilai AS k2, 0 as k3, 0 as k4 FROM bobot WHERE kode_aspek =  'K2' AND tahun = 2019
UNION ALL
SELECT no_daftar, nama, kode_aspek, 0 AS k1, 0 AS k2, nilai as k3, 0 as k4 FROM bobot WHERE kode_aspek =  'K3' AND tahun = 2019
UNION ALL
SELECT no_daftar, nama, kode_aspek, 0 AS k1, 0 AS k2, 0 as k3, nilai as k4 FROM bobot WHERE kode_aspek =  'K4' AND tahun = 2019
) AS a
LEFT JOIN aspek b ON ( a.kode_aspek = b.kode_aspek )
GROUP BY a.no_daftar, a.kode_aspek
) as SEMI
```

The link for download the database here :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a5BNT34v3keKwFaPxV73C48NzKQho34O/view?usp=sharing

I expect that the output will be every 1 primary key have 4 output in every row but the actual result is 4 rows with null expresion

Comment: mysql or sql.-server ???

Comment: in mysql sir, make a stored procedure with this syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would give the results you would expect.  But instead of using a UNION you could try with conditional aggregation to pivot the K's.

For example this untested notepad scribble.

```
SELECT 
 bb.no_daftar, 
 bb.nama, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN bb.kode_aspek = 'K1' THEN bb.total_nilai/kr.cnt ELSE 0 END) AS k1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN bb.kode_aspek = 'K2' THEN bb.total_nilai/kr.cnt ELSE 0 END) AS k2,
 SUM(CASE WHEN bb.kode_aspek = 'K3' THEN bb.total_nilai/kr.cnt ELSE 0 END) AS k3,
 SUM(CASE WHEN bb.kode_aspek = 'K4' THEN bb.total_nilai/kr.cnt ELSE 0 END) AS k4
FROM
(
SELECT 
     no_daftar, kode_aspek,
     MAX(nama) AS nama,
     SUM(nilai) AS total_nilai
    FROM bobot
    WHERE tahun = 2019
      AND kode_aspek IN ('K1','K2','K3','K4')
    GROUP BY no_daftar, kode_aspek
) bb
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT kode_aspek, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM kriteria
    WHERE kode_aspek IN('K1','K2','K3','K4')
    GROUP BY kode_aspek
) kr ON kr.kode_aspek = bb.kode_aspek
GROUP BY bb.no_daftar, bb.nama
```

Comment: Thanks Luk,it's realy help me very much for solve the main program for the report result